# Knots bleeding thru on the deck

Tags: staining

The knots on my treated lumber deck have been bleeding thru the solid color latex stain.  After scraping off the mounds of sap, I coated the knots with two coats of amber shellac.
My question is: Can I just apply the solid color stain latex stain over the top of the shellacked areas??  If not, what is the proper surface preparation?
Thanks
ET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I just apply the solid color stain latex stain over the top of the shellacked areas??

Absolutely, paints and most other coatings stick very well to shellac.

But shellac is not a waterproof coating so I don't know how well this will hold up over time.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Graphus, you should be fine from an adhesion point of view, but may have issues with shellac not being waterproof.  Further, I don't think that shellac will do much to stop sap seeping from the wood.

I would suggest a CPES-type product instead of shellac next time.  It will both hold up to weather better and stabilize the wood better.

Comment: Re. the shellac in general for this task, shellac is the go-to knot sealer. In my part of the world what used to be sold commonly as "patent knotting" was just a basic heavy cut of brown shellac.